# Format date using moment Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to format date using moment in Angularjs but its not working for me. Here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sed6x5e8/ and below is my code.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="miniapp">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <div>
            Actual Date: {{date}}
            <br><br>
            Formatted Date: {{formattedDate}}
        </div>

    </div>    
</div>
```

JS:

```
var $scope;
var app = angular.module('miniapp', [])
function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.date = '2/13/2015';
    $scope.formattedDate = moment($scope.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
}
```

Comment: Why are you declaring `var $scope` outside your controller? And you have en error in the console, `moment` isn't included.

Comment: Add `moment` library to your project - http://jsfiddle.net/sed6x5e8/1/

Comment: I copied from internet. I am new to Angularjs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've used [angular-moment](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment) successfully in a project of mine. It has a filter that alows you to format the date. Example from the README:

```
<span>{{message.time | amDateFormat:'dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'}}</span>
```

Comment: @user3842029 np. P.S. Not sure why the answer got down voted. Would the person care to explain?

Comment: Any chance you could elaborate on your answer? I'm not clear how to implement it. I want to {{getDate}} from the back end to display within ngrepeat but I can't put that between {{}} . . . {{{{getDate}}|date}} throws an error.

Comment: <span> {{ obj.get('Start') | date: 'shortDate'}}</span>.

Comment: I downvoted this. This functionality is built into angular using the date filter, there is absolutely no need to bring in another library to do it.

Comment: @ribsies well it seems like you're assuming that the OP's requirements stop at just formatting dates... moment.js has some other features that they might be using. I'm aware of angular's date filter but i just answered based on what was asked.

Comment: @rashadb Could you provide more details on the error  or an example in a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/)? I'm not entirely sure what to elaborate on... but based on what you've said `{{getDate | amDateFormat:'...'}}` should work provided that `getDate` is a valid date(object/string/num). Using the name `getDate` also makes it seem like it's a function so perhaps `{{getDate() | amDateFormat:'...'}}` would work... and similarly `obj.get('Start')` would need to return a valid date. Finally,  as indicated by @ribsies if the only thing you're doing is formatting dates then try out angular's date filter.

Comment: No, I posted the answer after I figured it out. I happened to find it after much searching not too long after I posted the first comment.

Answer (score 14):

AngularJS has a built in filter for dates. You do not need to use moment, waste of resources.

```
<span>{{message.time | date}}</span>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Comment: Does Angular support localization?

Answer (score 0):

[sample example](https://codepen.io/wfsouza23/pen/jovvxr)

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.constant("moment", moment);

app.controller("ctrl", function($scope, moment) {
    $scope.date = new moment().format("D/MMM/YYYY");
    var dat1 = new moment();
    $scope.date3 = dat1.add('5', 'd').format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
});
```

**Html**

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.constant("moment", moment);

app.controller("ctrl", function($scope, moment) {
    $scope.date = new moment().format("D/MMM/YYYY");
    var dat1 = new moment();
    $scope.date3 = dat1.add('5', 'd').format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    {{ date }} 
  </br>
  </br>
  {{date3}}
</div>
```